# calculate number of lines in file using c

Tags: c, pointers, casting, segmentation-fault

Im trying to create a C program to calculate number of lines in a file.
But it is throwing an error as shown below.

Please check and let me know where i am going wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int counter(char *file_name);

int  counter(char *file_name){
char ch;
FILE *fp;
int l=0;
fp = fopen(file_name,"r");

while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
{
    if ((ch) == '\n')
    {
        l=l+1;
    }
}
printf("hi there \n");
fclose(fp);
return l;
}

int main() {

    char file_n,*file_name;
    int result;
    printf("Enter File Name: ");
    scanf("%s",&file_n);
    file_name=file_n;
    result=counter(file_name);
    printf("%d",result);
    printf("%s\n",&file_n);
    return 0;
}
```

PFB the execution code:

```
subbi@subbi-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ls
bar.txt  DWA calssification.py  myp.c  prj1  tes.c  test.c  test.py  tikinter  tkinter_actual  Untitled Document  wctester
subbi@subbi-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ gcc myp.c 
myp.c: In function ‘main’:
myp.c:30:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     file_name=file_n;
              ^
subbi@subbi-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ./a.out 
Enter File Name: bar.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
subbi@subbi-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: You are using scanf with %s to parse a string but assigning it to a single char variable.

Comment: Yes.  'char file_n,*file_name;'   One is a pointer, the other is not, so 'file_name=file_n;' is a type mismatch.

Comment: If you change `file_n` to a sufficiently large array, such as `char file_n[200]`, it will probably work (but won't be safe from buffer overflows.

Comment: You should also change variable `char ch` to `int ch` because the constant `EOF` is not necessarily representable by a `char`.

Comment: Seems funny to use the phrase 'type mismatch' with  C problem:)

Comment: @Ian Abbott: Or better yet something like "%199s" (with char file_n[200]). No buffer overflows then.

Comment: Why prompt the user for the file name at all and not use the command-line arguments?

Answer (score 4):

`ch` **must** be of `int` type;

```
while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ) // fails if ch is of type char
```

See [`fgetc()` description in (a draft of) the C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1).